# Assignment on sorting a list

Tags: java, sortedlist

I'm very close to being done, but can't quite figure out how to tie everything together. I have the separate methods responsible for their particular task, but i feel like my cohesion is really bad. not real sure how they tie together and what needs to be called in main. The goal here is to read a text file from the command line and list the words in the story lexicographically.

```
% java Ten < story.txt
Word      Occurs
====      ======
a          21
animal      3
 .
 .
 .
zebra       1
%
```

Here's my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ten2
{
    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String word;
        List sortedList = new List();
        word = nextWord(input);

        while (word!=null) {
            sortedList.insert(word);
            word = nextWord(input);
        }

        sortedList.printWords();        
    }

    private static String nextWord(Scanner input)
    {   
        // return null if there are no more words
        if (input.hasNext() == false )
            return null;
        // take next element, convert to lowercase, store in s
        else { 
            String s = input.next().toLowerCase() ;
            // empty string
            String token = "";
            // loop through s and concatonate chars onto token
            for (int i =0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) == true)
                    token = token + s.charAt(i);
                else if (s.charAt(i) == '\'' )
                    token = token + s.charAt(i);
                else if (s.charAt(i) == '-')
                    token = token + s.charAt(i);
            }
            return token; 
        }      
    }   
}

class List
{
    /*
     * Internally, the list of strings is represented by a linked chain 
     * of nodes belonging to the class ListNode. The strings are stored
     * in lexicographical order.
     */
    private static class ListNode
    {
        // instance variables for ListNode objects
        public String word;
        public ListNode next;
        public int count;

        // Listnode constructor               
        public ListNode(String w, ListNode nxt)
        {  
            word = w; // token from nextWord()?
            next = nxt; // link to next ListNode
            count = 1; // number of word occurences
        }
    }

    // instance variables for List object
    private ListNode first;
    private int numWords;

    // constructor postcondition: creates new Listnode storing object
    public List()
    { 
        first = null; // pointer to ListNode?
        numWords = 0; // counter for nodes in list
    }


    //  Insert a specified word into the list, keeping the list 
    //  in lexicographical order.
    public void insert(String word)
    {    
        // check if first is null
        if (first == null) {
            ListNode newNode;
            newNode = addNode(word, null);
            first = newNode;          
        }   

        // else if (first is not null) check if word matches first word in List
        else if (word.equals(first.word)) {
            // increase count
            first.count++;
            }

        // else (first is not null && doesn't match first word) 
        else {  
            ListNode newNode;
            ListNode current;
            current = first;
            ListNode previous;
            previous = null;
            int cmp =  word.compareTo(current.word);

            /*
             * Fist two cases of empty list and word already existing
             * handled in above if and else statements, now by using compareTo() 
             * method between the words, the insertion postion can be determined.
             * Links between ListNode variables current and previous need to be
             * modified in order to maintain the list
             */


            // loop as long as value comparing to is positive
            // when compareTo() returns positive this means the "word" parameter is greater than the word in the list 
            while ((cmp >0) && (current.next != null)) {
                previous = current;    
                current = current.next;
                cmp =  word.compareTo(current.word);
            }

            // insert after current at end of list
            if ((cmp >0 && current.next == null)) {
                newNode = addNode(word, null);
                current.next = newNode;
            }

            // increments count when word already exists
            else if (cmp==0) {
                current.count++;
            }

            // else (cmp < 0) we insert BEFORE current
            else { 
                newNode = addNode(word, current);

                // first node in list comes after new word
                if (previous == null) {
                    first = newNode;       
                }         

                else {
                    // inserting new word in middle of list
                    previous.next = newNode;
                }
            }       
        }
    }

    // method to add new ListNode and increase counter
    private ListNode addNode(String word, ListNode next)
    {
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(word, next);
        numWords++;
        return newNode;
    }


    // Returns a string array that contains all the words in the list.  
    public String[] getWords() 
    {
        String[] Words = new String[numWords];
        ListNode current = first;
        int i =0;

        while (current != null) {     
            Words[i] = current.word;
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }
        return Words;
    }   


    // Returns an int array that contains the number of times 
    // each word occurs in the list.  
    public int[] getNumbers()
    {
        int[] Numbers = new int[numWords];
        ListNode current = first;
        int i =0;

        while (current != null) {
            Numbers[i] = current.count;
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }
        return Numbers;
    }


    // Outputs the string array and int array containing all the   
    // words in the list and the number of times each occurs.
    public void printWords()
    {
        int[] Numbers = getNumbers();
        String[] Words = getWords();

        System.out.println("Word   \t    \t    Occurs");
        System.out.println("====   \t    \t    ======");

        for (int i =0; i < numWords; i++) { 
            System.out.println(Words[i] + " \t " + Numbers[i]);   
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would start by defining what you want your program to do, which you've already done:

> The goal here is to read a text file from the command line and list the words in the story lexicographically.

You're main function does this *almost*.  Basically, what you need is a loop to tie it together:

```
public static void main(String [] arg)
{
    // print out your initial information first (i.e. your column headers)
    // ...

    List sortedList = new List();
    String word = nextWord();

    // now, the question is... what is the end condition of the loop?
    // probably that there aren't any more words, so word in this case
    // will be null
    while (word != null)
    {
      sortedList.insert(word);
      word = nextWord();
    }

    // now, your list takes care of the sorting, so let's just print the list
    sortedList.printWords();
}
```

I think that's all there is to it.  Normally, I don't like to post solutions to homework questions, but in this case, since you already had all of the code and you just needed a little nudge to drive you in the right direction, I think it's fine.

There are a few things I noticed that are incorrect with your

Your list constructor has a 'void' return type - there should be no return type on constructors:

```
public List() //make an empty list
{ 
    first = null;
    numWords = 0;
}
```

The 'else' statement in this method is unneeded:

```
    public static String nextWord()
    {   
        if ( keyboard.hasNext() == false )
            return null;
        else {   
            String start =  keyboard.next().toLowerCase() ;
            String organized = "";
            for (int i =0; i < start.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isLetter(start.charAt(i)) == true)
                    organized = organized + start.charAt(i);

                else if (start.charAt(i) == '\'' )
                    organized = organized + start.charAt(i);

                else if (start.charAt(i) == '-')
                    organized = organized + start.charAt(i);
            }
            return organized;       
        }   
    }
```

So, this should be:

```
public static String nextWord()
{   
    if ( keyboard.hasNext() == false )
        return null;
    String start =  keyboard.next().toLowerCase() ;
    String organized = "";
    for (int i =0; i < start.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(start.charAt(i)) == true)
            organized = organized + start.charAt(i);

        else if (start.charAt(i) == '\'' )
            organized = organized + start.charAt(i);

        else if (start.charAt(i) == '-')
            organized = organized + start.charAt(i);
    }
    return organized;   
}
```

If you want to use a BufferedReader, it's pretty easy.  Just set it up in your main method:

```
  if (arg.length > 0)
  {
    // open our file and read everything into a string buffer
    BufferedReader bRead = null;
    try {
      bRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arg[0]));
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(0);
    }
    setupScanner(bRead);
  }
```

Then, create a new method that sets up the scanner object:

```
public static void setupScanner(BufferedReader rdr)
{
  keyboard = new Scanner(rdr);
}
```

And then just pass it in on the command line (i.e. java ten2 [filename])

Comment: Also, just a quick reference - I probably would've done it a bit different.  You probably want to have the user specify a *filename* as an argument, and then open a BufferedReader, but I guess that's more of a style issue.  :)

Comment: thanks for the assistance. was getting a compiler error in my print method. dropped the "List" reference from getWords() and getNumbers(). it now compiles, but i'm not sure exactly how to run the test on the .txt file from main. i'm using BlueJ and not sure how to see the output. the JVM just keeps running.

Comment: Hm... I've never used BlueJ as an IDE before.  I would actually recommend Eclipse.  The other thing you can do is compile it using BlueJ, then navigate to your classes/ directory in the project directory using the terminal (either windows cmd or just the terminal, depending on what OS you're using).  Then, just type java Ten2 < somestory.txt

Comment: yeah this lab, like most assigned programming exercises seem to go against my natural logic in terms of how i would construct it. this doesn't actually need any reference to the .txt file, as Java has that ability built-in. i feel like the buffered stream would be the way to go. so this just looks at each word, then builds the arrays. my newb issue is how i print the returned arrays from getNumbers() and get Words(). i keep feeling the need to have parameters, and keep running into the "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error.. one last wall to break through. argh!

Comment: I edited my above post to give you some clues as to how I would accomplish this reader idea.  The reason nothing is printing is because the code isn't incrementing numWords correctly.  There is an error in the logic that causes numWords to be 0, even though there are words in the list.

Comment: BlueJ is a teaching IDE. It's a simplified environment that focuses on learning OOP, and leaves out things like bells and whistles like refactoring etc.

Comment: @Atomix:  So does BlueJ have a debugger?  ;)

Comment: awesome. got everything compiling, now i just need to find out what's going on with numWords. hmmm...

Comment: i've tried working my way through the logic, tried modifying numWords so it looks at the length of the arrays.. i don't know. i can't express in words how frustrating it is to put so much time into something, and consistently fail to actually solve the problem myself.. it is seriously depressing. thanks for all the help though guys.. and if you wanna throw any more hints my way, feel free

Comment: @Bill:  Do you know how to use a debugger?  A debugger allows you to step through the code, one statement at a time, in order to verify that your variables and code execution path are what you expect them to be.  Again, I know this might be a little bit of overkill for this assignment, but I would highly recommend using Eclipse as a tool for developing Java code.  The Eclipse debugger (which you can execute by clicking the bug icon at the top of the screen) allows you to do this easily.  A good tutorial I've found is available at: http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html

Comment: yeah i've played around with them a little. the one in blueJ isn't allowing me to set breakpoints for some reason, maybe because it's private? maybe i'll give eclipse a shot. i think i tried using it when i started this java course, but didn't like it for some reason or another.

Comment: well it's official. i dont understand inner classes, linked lists, or any of this stuff.. i dont even know HOW to learn this stuff.. because everything i do is wrong. i quit

Comment: @jwir. Good question. To be honest, it's all about the objects, so I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ten2
{
    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String word;
        List sortedList = new List();
        word = nextWord(input);

        while (word!=null) {
            sortedList.insert(word);
            word = nextWord(input);
        }

        sortedList.printWords();        
    }

    private static String nextWord(Scanner input)
    {   
        // return null if there are no more words
        if (input.hasNext() == false )
            return null;
        // take next element, convert to lowercase, store in s
        else { 
            String s = input.next().toLowerCase() ;
            // empty string
            String token = "";
            // loop through s and concatonate chars onto token
            for (int i =0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) == true)
                    token = token + s.charAt(i);
                else if (s.charAt(i) == '\'' )
                    token = token + s.charAt(i);
                else if (s.charAt(i) == '-')
                    token = token + s.charAt(i);
            }
            return token; 
        }      
    }   
}

class List
{
    /*
     * Internally, the list of strings is represented by a linked chain 
     * of nodes belonging to the class ListNode. The strings are stored
     * in lexicographical order.
     */
    private static class ListNode
    {
        // instance variables for ListNode objects
        public String word;
        public ListNode next;
        public int count;

        // Listnode constructor               
        public ListNode(String w, ListNode nxt)
        {  
            word = w; // token from nextWord()?
            next = nxt; // link to next ListNode
            count = 1; // number of word occurences
        }
    }

    // instance variables for List object
    private ListNode first;
    private int numWords;

    // constructor postcondition: creates new Listnode storing object
    public List()
    { 
        first = null; // pointer to ListNode?
        numWords = 0; // counter for nodes in list
    }


    //  Insert a specified word into the list, keeping the list 
    //  in lexicographical order.
    public void insert(String word)
    {    
        // check if first is null
        if (first == null) {
            ListNode newNode;
            newNode = addNode(word, null);
            first = newNode;          
        }   

        // else if (first is not null) check if word matches first word in List
        else if (word.equals(first.word)) {
            // increase count
            first.count++;
            }

        // else (first is not null && doesn't match first word) 
        else {  
            ListNode newNode;
            ListNode current;
            current = first;
            ListNode previous;
            previous = null;
            int cmp =  word.compareTo(current.word);

            /*
             * Fist two cases of empty list and word already existing
             * handled in above if and else statements, now by using compareTo() 
             * method between the words, the insertion postion can be determined.
             * Links between ListNode variables current and previous need to be
             * modified in order to maintain the list
             */


            // loop as long as value comparing to is positive
            // when compareTo() returns positive this means the "word" parameter is greater than the word in the list 
            while ((cmp >0) && (current.next != null)) {
                previous = current;    
                current = current.next;
                cmp =  word.compareTo(current.word);
            }

            // insert after current at end of list
            if ((cmp >0 && current.next == null)) {
                newNode = addNode(word, null);
                current.next = newNode;
            }

            // increments count when word already exists
            else if (cmp==0) {
                current.count++;
            }

            // else (cmp < 0) we insert BEFORE current
            else { 
                newNode = addNode(word, current);

                // first node in list comes after new word
                if (previous == null) {
                    first = newNode;       
                }         

                else {
                    // inserting new word in middle of list
                    previous.next = newNode;
                }
            }       
        }
    }

    // method to add new ListNode and increase counter
    private ListNode addNode(String word, ListNode next)
    {
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(word, next);
        numWords++;
        return newNode;
    }


    // Returns a string array that contains all the words in the list.  
    public String[] getWords() 
    {
        String[] Words = new String[numWords];
        ListNode current = first;
        int i =0;

        while (current != null) {     
            Words[i] = current.word;
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }
        return Words;
    }   


    // Returns an int array that contains the number of times 
    // each word occurs in the list.  
    public int[] getNumbers()
    {
        int[] Numbers = new int[numWords];
        ListNode current = first;
        int i =0;

        while (current != null) {
            Numbers[i] = current.count;
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }
        return Numbers;
    }


    // Outputs the string array and int array containing all the   
    // words in the list and the number of times each occurs.
    public void printWords()
    {
        int[] Numbers = getNumbers();
        String[] Words = getWords();

        System.out.println("Word   \t    \t    Occurs");
        System.out.println("====   \t    \t    ======");

        for (int i =0; i < numWords; i++) { 
            System.out.println(Words[i] + " \t " + Numbers[i]);   
        }
    }      
}
```